# Passing Value of Property back to SuperClass

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, watchos-2

I have two classes Model and View Controller. Model is providing value for View Controller and View Controller is returning new value to Model.

```
  class Model : NSObject {
         var session : Int = 0 
         }

  class ViewController : WKInterfaceController {

        var newSession = Model().session
        let counter = 5

        for var index = 0; index < counter.count ; ++index {
            newSession++
        }
   }

    print(Model.session) // How to set value of Model.session === newSession?
```

How to provide Model.session with the new calculated value of newSession?

Comment: You need to learn what object-oriented programming is. I suggest you start right at the beginning of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html

Answer (score 1):

This line is meaningless:

```
print(Model.session)
```

In fact, I'm surprised it compiles. `session` is an *instance* property, not a property of the Model *class*. You would need an actual instance of Model before you can talk to it. But you don't have one; in the first line you initialized one for a moment, but then you threw it away:

```
var newSession = Model().session
```

You need to *retain* an instance of Model so that it *persists*. You're not doing that. For example:

```
class ViewController : WKInterfaceController {
    let theModel = Model()
    // ...
}
```

*Now* you have a persistent Model instance, namely `theModel`. Now you can access `theModel.session` as much as you like.

Comment: Ok, so if I call theModel.session = 5, how do I change the value of Model.session with the same value?

Comment: You didn't understand matts answer because you are missing the basics. As he said - read his book.